# How to add a HashMap to a HashMap of HashMaps without it getting overwritten

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two HashMaps.

```
 Map<Integer, HashMap<String,Integer>> outer = new HashMap<Integer,HashMap<String,Integer>>();
     HashMap<String, Integer> inner =new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

I have a loop that is updating inner with each iteration

```
inner.put(word, docEnum.freq());
```

After each iteration I add inner to outer using a global variable (public static HashMap tempMap = null;)

```
        tempMap = inner;
        outer.put(count, tempMap);
        count++;
```

When I print outer I find that every element contains the final version of inner. 
How can I prevent this data from getting overwritten. I have taken the advice of a few other questions on the topic by passing inner into a global variable but it does not seem to work.

Thanks

Comment: You realise that you're just storing **references** in your HashMap, right?  If you want each to be different, you'd need to explicitly copy.

Comment: Don't make `tempMap = new Hashmap` is probably the correct solution, but without showing a [mcve] it's difficult to know what you are doing and why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The general java concept is call by reference.
If you do not want to overwrite the information you have to copy the inner map every time or create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the **inner** at each iteration. But it will consume more memory.

```
tempMap = inner;
outer.put(count, tempMap.clone());
count++;
```

This is because the tempMap is saved in the HashMap by reference, not as a separate object.